# New Google Chrome update changed menu text size

Tags: google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

New google chrome update some changed its layout. Added scroll in right click option as well as in menu. Is there any way to make fonts smaller or change the layout of this menu/right-click dialogue box.
[image]
I try to google it and try to find way from community but did not get any solution.
If anyone have solution it will be much appreciated!
Thank you!

I tried google chrome help and documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put this in the address bar `chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023-top-chrome-font` and hit enter.
2. Change the value in the drop down menu to **Disabled**.
3. Restart Chrome in order to activate the changes.

Comment: On my case (Chromium v121), I've to disable this similar flag: `chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023` instead